# Remove Class Not Working in a node List

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove a class form a nodelist? In this case I need to remove first then when the button is clicked the class will apply.

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-menu a');

buttons.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', addActive);
});

function addActive(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const element = event.target;
  const id = element.getAttribute('href');
  const sectionId = document.querySelector(id);

  **buttons.classList.remove('active');
  element.classList.add("active");**
  sectionId.classList.add('active');
}
```

Comment: You need to use a `.forEach()`, just like you did to add the event handler.

Comment: is it ok to use Jquery ?

Comment: You don't need to, just attach the event like you normally would without jQuery 

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: Still not working, I don't know why..

Answer (score 0):

`classList` only works for a single element and does not work for a NodeList.

In your function, you need to loop through the `buttons` NodeList and perform the `remove()` method for each button. For example:

```js
for (const button of buttons)
{
    button.classList.remove('active');
}
```